# jQuery .remove is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been bashing my head at this for a couple days.

```
Blog.closeNewPostForm = function(event) {
    var $createPost = $('#create-post');
    $createPost.addClass('bounceOut animated');
    setTimeout(function() {
       $createPost.slideUp('normal', function() {
           $createPost.remove();
       });
    }, 1000);
};
```

This code runs well until it hits the remove() method/function at which the console then shows an error that remove() is not a function.

Do you guys have any idea on what's going on? It's driving me crazy >.<

EDIT:

It may probably help to see a console.log screenshot [image] and its github link https://github.com/Lavoaster/LightBlog

Comment: Strange... your code looks right to me...

Comment: Are you sure `"#create-post"` exists? Could be the selection is empty?

Comment: It does exists since both the classes are added to the element and slideUp is executed.

Comment: You appear to have something else going on with your code. It works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KF5xx/).

Comment: You're overwriting the remove method somewhere in your code. It wouldn't say it's not a function unless it's something else like a string. Do `console.log($createPost.remove);` to find out what's in there (or put a breakpoint and type `$createPost.remove` on the JS console).

Comment: I updated the question with a console.log screenshot and a repository link.

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/9XbL8/1

Comment: There are JS files referenced in your master file that aren't in your repository. You should really put this up on a live site or replicate on fiddle.

Comment: @user1506980 They are installed via bower, trying to keep dependencies out of the repo :P Will get up a live version in a moment.

Comment: You are calling `$createPost.remove();` at two places inside file `blog.js`. Is it possible that both setTimeout() are called almost at same time. One remove() succeeds and the others has no valid object any more?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic No that wouldn't be the problem as they would be triggered for different events, successful response after form submission, clicking the form close button and deleting a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I found out I had a bad dependency somewhere that bower thought was fine and never updated/replaced, after deleting my components directory and running `bower update` again it was fixed.